# Apple Mail and Applescript

Tags: applescript

I have has this script working fine on Outlook 2011 for Mac all on a local machine.

I have now found out my "rules" will now work on Apple mail after all these years.
The last part of the rule is to run this script which then sends an HTML email back to the sender.
If I change the tell application "Microsoft Outlook" to tell the application "Mail", I keep getting Syntax Errors and it highlights the "mail folder" telling me it is wrong.
I am stumped.
I am using Exchange with the Mail app. Not sure if that may be the issue?

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set replyToMessage to message 1 of mail folder "•HOT FOLDER•"
    if (replyToMessage is "") then
        log ("NOTHING SELECTED!")
        return
    end if
    set replyMessageSubj to subject of replyToMessage
    set replyMessage to reply to replyToMessage without opening window
    set contentHTML to "Vault:Users:vault:Documents:VAULT:Digital_Subscription_Reply:Digital_issue22.html" as alias
    set contentHTML to read contentHTML
    set the content of replyMessage to contentHTML
    set the subject of replyMessage to "Vault Digital Issue - Issue 22"
    send replyMessage
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

Every scriptable application has its own scripting dictionary with its own unique terminology. We can't just change `tell application "Microsoft Outlook"` to `tell application "Mail"` and expect it to work, because Mail and Outlook use different keywords for their equivalent objects.  I don't have outlook installed on my machine, so I can't compile or run the original script, but I've modified it as best I can to use Mail terminology. No guarantee this will work, but it will compile and run so you can (at least) test it.

```
tell application "Mail"
    set replyToMessage to message 1 of mailbox "•HOT FOLDER•"
    if (replyToMessage is "") then
        log ("NOTHING SELECTED!")
        return
    end if
    set replyMessageSubj to subject of replyToMessage
    set replyMessage to reply replyToMessage without opening window
    set contentHTML to "Vault:Users:vault:Documents:VAULT:Digital_Subscription_Reply:Digital_issue22.html" as alias
    set contentHTML to read contentHTML
    set the content of replyMessage to contentHTML
    set the subject of replyMessage to "Vault Digital Issue - Issue 22"
    send replyMessage
end tell
```

When you're in Script Editor, select "Open Dictionary..." from the File menu and scroll down to open the Mail scripting dictionary. That will give you all the relevant terminology for scripting Mail.app.

Comment: Thanks heaps for that Ted. I have used that code to no avail but not sure of it is just not possible in Apple Mail at all or I have the file path wrong. I looked at the Dictionary thing and it still made no sense to me. Thanks for trying.